# htaccess block requests by querystring

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There is a way to block all the requests with a certain querystring?

I should block all the request that have "?userid=1234" or "&userid=1234"

For example:

```
/directory/page.php?userid=1234&var2=abc&var3=..
/directory/page.php?var1=test&userid=1234&var2=abc&var3=..
```

The directory and the page are always the same.

I know it's possibile, but i'm not sure how..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check `QUERY_STRING` and test if it contains `userid=1234`.
If so, then forbid it

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \buserid=1234\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Note: `\b` is a **word** boundary anchor. Having it before *and* after the pattern we want to match makes sure that the rule will match *exactly* on `userid=1234` and not on, e.g., `xxxuserid=1234` or `userid=1234xxx`.