# PHP Warnings from malicious access

Tags: php, .htaccess

We are getting spurious `PHP Warnings` which we cannot duplicate.

All PHP Warning occur when we the following URL is `[  .php?prod='0=A ]` is accessed.

All the domain addresses appear to be far-flung and seemingly unrelated to us or indeed each other and could well be malicious. We block an ip address and it pops up with a new ip address.

As I say we can't duplicate the error so I'm wondering if anyone has seen similar or has a suggestion as to how we can permanently block all access to `[  .php?prod='0=A ]`

I know this is perhaps not the best forum but frankly I'm stumped.

PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: Looks like a poor attempt at SQL injection. Whats the error/warning?

Comment: Ok... what's the warning? Or the code? We can't read your mind

Comment: You can set an `.htaccess` rule to block the `prod='0=A` querystring or a similar pattern. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632327/htaccess-block-requests-by-querystring

Answer (score 0):

You can configure web server to block unwanted requests. Here is example of blocking `?prod='0=A` using nginx:

```
    # %27 means ' character
    if ($arg_prod = "%270=A") {
        return 403;
    }
```

Also I suggest you to take a look to ready WAF solutions like mod_security or naxsi to block suspicious requests automatically.

Comment: You are not quite right, in nginx configuration files `=` is used for comparing.

Comment: Where should I placed this - htaccess or before head of web page would suit us best.

Comment: This is an example for nginx configuration file. For a .htaccess (Apache) variant take a look here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77183

Comment: Okay but how about a partial string?

Comment: I'm not clearly understand what you mean, but you can use regular expressions in RewriteRule to match any string which you want.

Comment: You are correct. The nginx doesn't do any assignments so this would work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to fetch result form query but result is certainly false and it means there is a database error.

here is [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) doc check this

Comment: If its a database error how come we can't reproduce the error?

Comment: you can check that query result true or false before fetch result

Answer (score 0):

You can block such urls from your htaccess file with RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?=%27|%22).*
RewriteRule ^.* - [F]
```

This rule will throw a 403 server response to forbid such urls. Instead of throwing a 403 Forbidden response you may redirect to index page

**%27** - URL encoded value for single quotes
**%22** - URL encoded value for double quotes